# Spectral Representation of $T$

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products, spectral-theory, projection, adjoint-operators

> the spectral family of the operator $T:\ell^2\rightarrow\ell^2$ defined by
> $$T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,....)=(\xi_1/1,\xi_2/2,\xi_3/3,....)$$

I am trying to get the application of  [Spectral theorem of bounded self-adjoint linear operator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4606362/need-explanation-of-spectral-theorem-for-bounded-self-adjoint-linear-operators-v).
All I know is that the set of eigenvalues is $\{1/n:n\in\mathbb Z_+\}$ and corresponding eigenvectors are $\{e_n:n\in\mathbb Z_+\}$ having $1$ at $n^{th}$ position and zero otherwise.

*Solution*:

$T_{\lambda}(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,....)=T(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,....)-\lambda(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,....)=(\xi_1/1,\xi_2/2,\xi_3/3,....)-(\lambda\xi_1,\lambda\xi_2,\lambda\xi_3,....)=(\xi_1(1/1-\lambda),\xi_2(1/2-\lambda),\xi_3(1/3-\lambda),....)$

Hence,$T_{\lambda}^2(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,....)=T_{\lambda}(\xi_1(1/1-\lambda),\xi_2(1/2-\lambda),\xi_3(1/3-\lambda),....)=(\xi_1(1/1-\lambda)^2,\xi_2(1/2-\lambda)^2,\xi_3(1/3-\lambda)^2,..)=(1/1-\lambda)^2,(1/2-\lambda)^2,(1/3-\lambda)^2,...)(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,....).$

So,$T_\lambda^2=((1/1-\lambda)^2,(1/2-\lambda)^2,(1/3-\lambda)^2,...)\implies (T_\lambda^2)^{1/2}=((1/1-\lambda),(1/2-\lambda),(1/3-\lambda),...)$

Now,$T_{\lambda}^+=\frac{1}{2}((T_\lambda+(T_\lambda^2)^{1/2})=\frac{1}{2}(2(1/1-\lambda),2(1/2-\lambda),2(1/3-\lambda),..)=((1/1-\lambda),(1/2-\lambda),(1/3-\lambda),...)$

Since, the eigenvalues are $1,1/2,1/3,1/4,...$

Computing the Null spaces

$\mathcal N(T_{1}^+)=(\xi_1,0,0,0,...)$

$\mathcal N(T_{1/2}^+)=(0,\xi_2,0,0,...)$

$\mathcal N(T_{1/3}^+)=(0,0,\xi_3,0,...)$  and so on

Computing the projections $E_\lambda=\mathcal H\rightarrow\ \mathcal N(T_{\lambda}^+)$,we get

$E_1(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)=(\xi_1,0,0,0,...)$

$E_{1/2}(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)=(0,\xi_2,0,0,...)$

$E_{1/3}(\xi_1,\xi_2,\xi_3,...)=(0,0,\xi_3,0,0,0,...)$ and so on is the spectral family.

*above I've found the Spectral family of $T$*.I want to know **How can T  be represented in the form as given in the following theorem?**

**Spectral theorem for Bounded Self-Adjoint Linear operators**

> Let $T:\mathcal H\rightarrow \mathcal H$ be a bounded self-adjoint
> linear operator on a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.Then $T$ has
> the spectral representation $$T=\int_{m-0}^M\lambda dE_{\lambda}$$
> Where $\mathcal E=(E_\lambda)$ is the spectral family associated with
> $T,$the integral is to be understood in the sense of uniform operator
> convergence,and for all $x,y\in \mathcal H$,$$\langle
>  Tx,y\rangle=\int_{m-0}^M\lambda dw(\lambda)$$
>
> Where the integral is an ordinary Riemann Stieltjes integral.

Comment: This is a compact operator and it has  a simpler spectral decomposition. $E_{\lambda}$'s are discrete mesures.

Comment: @geetha290krm: thanks for responding...as i'm naive in this ...i do not know "what is discrete measure?"as for now i'm looking T as an application of the theorem, how can it be represented as given in the theorem?Can you give the representation explicitly?

Comment: You should read about spectral representation of compact self-adjoint operators. You will find it in Wikipedia.

Comment: The operator is represented by an infinite diagonal matrix. It's spectral representation is thus straightforward: $E_\lambda$ is the orthogonal projection on all eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues $\mu$ with $\mu<\lambda$ for $\lambda <1$ and $E_1=I.$ Hence $E_\lambda \xi =(0,\ldots, 0,\xi_n,\xi_{n+1},\ldots )$ where $n$ is the greatest positive integer such that $\lambda >{1\over n}$ for $\lambda<1.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: But, your representation does not contain the integration sign?

Comment: Once $E_\lambda$ are identified we get $$T=\int\limits_{0^-}^1\lambda dE_\lambda$$